# Average Sample Number using Page's CUSUM procedure?

Tags: r, statistics, sequential

I am trying reproduce the Table 1 results from the page 12 using the equation given the page 13.To access the journal article please click https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0605322.pdf. The corresponding equation is given below.

[image]

My `r code` is give below. Am I programmed correctly?

```
mytest=function(n,s,c1){
  t = sum(s)
  k=which.max(s[19:n]>=c1)
  if(k==1 && s[19]<c1) 
    return(c(n,0)) 
  else 
    return(c(k,1))
}


for (n in c(100,200,400)){

for (i in c(-0.5, -1.0)){
a1=0
c1 = 20
asn1=0
for (m in 1:1000){
  g=c(dnorm(n,0,1))
  f=c(dnorm(n,i,1))
  s = log(g/f)
  test=mytest(n,s,c1)
  a1=a1+test[2]
  asn1=asn1+test[1]
}

}
out <- list(power= a1/m, asn=asn1/m)
return(out)
}
```

But I am getting the following errors.

```
Error in if (k == 1 && s[19] < c1) return(c(n, 0)) else return(c(k, 1)) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Answer (score 0):

The first time you call `mytest`, you have `n=100, i=-0.5` which yields `s=NaN`. Therefore, you get an error on line `if(k==1 && s[19]<c1)` given that `s[19]=NaN`.

Here's a workaround, but you need to make sure it does what you expect/wish :

```
mytest=function(n,s,c1){

  if(is.na(s)) return(c(c1,1))  # skips if NaN

  t = sum(s)
  k=which.max(s[19:n]>=c1)

  if(k==1 && s[19]<c1) 
    return(c(n,0)) 
  else 
    return(c(k,1))
}
```

Comment: Do I need to change the value of `n`?

Comment: You will certainly get `0/0` quite often with such $n$. Try n values closer to zero because $\phi(n) \approx 0$ for $n > 3$. If you try `for (n in 1:4)` you won't get an error.

Comment: how to find the `cumsum` from `k to n` in R? Is that correct?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?